# PHPWebSockets, how sharing websocket application

Tags: php, websocket, sharing

I have PHPWebSocket application.
Proccess of starting server in server.php file is like

```
$Server = new PHPWebSocket(); 
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 3306);
```

and in index.html I have instance like this:

```
Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3306');
```

This is from example PHPWebSocket chat application which you can download here:
https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

This code above works fine, I had to firstly open cmd.exe and write in there : 
"php ./server.php" and then open in two browsers file index.html, and everything works. But my problem is that this works only on my computer of course. I mean, I would like to having opportunity to connect to this application from some other computers.
So I would like to making my own server, or install these files on some hosting, to that chat application works. I tried change in index.html inserting ws://my external ip  in instance of Server, but it doesn't work. 
Thanks for help

Comment: `$Server->wsStartServer('0.0.0.0', 3306);`  <-- Listen address, not destination address. 0.0.0.0 means listen for all traffic.

Comment: Yeah, I've changed that, but still if I typed my external IP address in index.html, it doesn't connect. What should I do to could connect to this server.php on some different computer?